# How to use getQuantityText with format argument so quantity can be used in string?

Tags: android, string-formatting, android-resources

With simple strings you use `Resources.getQuantityString(int, int, ...)` which lets you pass placeholder values. So the plural resource could use %d in the string, and you could insert the actual quantity.

I wish to use font markups `<b>` etc inside a plural. So Im looking at `Resources.getQuantityText(int, int)`. Unfortunately, you cannot pass placeholder values. We see in the source code, that in getQuantityString with placeholders, they use String.format.

Is there a workaround to use font formatting in plurals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's look at the "normal" case (the one that doesn't work). You have some plural resource, like this:

```
<plurals name="myplural">
    <item quantity="one">only 1 <b>item</b></item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$d <b>items</b></item>
</plurals>
```

And you use it in Java like this:

```
textView.setText(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.myplural, 2, 2));
```

As you found, this just causes you to see "2 items" with no bolding.

The solution is to convert the `<b>` tags in your resource to use html entities instead. For example:

```
<plurals name="myplural">
    <item quantity="one">only 1 &lt;b>item&lt;/b></item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$d &lt;b>items&lt;/b></item>
</plurals>
```

Now you need to add another step to the Java code to handle these html entities. (If you didn't change the java, you'd see "2 <b>items</b>".) Here's the updated code:

```
String withMarkup = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.myplural, 2, 2);
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(withMarkup));
```

Now you will successfully see "2 **items**".

Comment: Thanks! The best explanation I found online offered using both toHtml and fromHtml, so that the item strings could be normal markup. I do like this idea better, since it only requires one conversion.

Comment: For what it's worth, this solution is adapted from google's own developer docs. See "Styling with HTML Markup" here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 3):

Instead of escaping HTML tags, you can wrap your string in `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`:

```
<plurals name="myplural">
    <item quantity="one"><![CDATA[only 1 <b>item</b>]]></item>
    <item quantity="other"><![CDATA[%1$d <b>items</b>]]></item>
</plurals>
```

Also, in Kotlin you can create an extension function so that you can retrieve the styled plural with `resources.getQuantityText(R.plurals.myplural, 2, 2)`:

```
fun Resources.getQuantityText(id: Int, quantity: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): CharSequence {
    val html = getQuantityString(id, quantity, *formatArgs)
    return HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
}
```